# Angular file name renaming issue while creating new build ,

Tags: javascript, angular, caching, deployment, build

Angular file compiler conversion issue while creating new build even though I am using **--output-hashing=all** while creating new build in CLI.

1. I am assuming files name will be change after creating new build .
2. I have made some changes in my component files name still same after run the same command.

Is that any configuration issue while creating new build or I miss something ?

I am trying to **avoid Cache Busting** issue in angular and expecting compiled files name will be change in every time when I am trying to create new build

Comment: file name only change once there is any updates in the module. If we have the same file then the name will remain same in each build.

Comment: Thanks for response. @Sino Sindhu
 Then How can I handle Cache Busting issue ?